# ROS Answers SE migration: uvc_camera

Tags: ros, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was happily using uvc_camera in my development.
Everything was working ok. Then I performed a
linux upgrade that said one package was being removed
and now I don't have uvc_camera.
I don't seem to be able to down load it from
camera_umd.
Is there a replacement?
I have tried upgrading to electric but that doesn't have uvc_camera.
Also I now cannot rosmake my code. the package seems to have cturtle
hard coded. is there a upgrade process for taking packages built
on one version to work on a later version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12166/uvc_camera/) by [JohnC](https://answers.ros.org/users/836/johnc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using ROS's unstable distribution on Ubuntu 11.10? If so, the immediate problem is that the image_common stack isn't yet building for that combination of ROS and Ubuntu.

You might have better luck with another UVC driver if you find one that doesn't use image_transport (for JPEG/Theora streams) or camera_info_manager (for CameraInfo), but anything that uses those or other components of image_common will be missing from the deb repository.

Alternatively, you could try building image_common and camera_umd from source, or you could switch to electric.

---

Originally posted by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) with karma: 438 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnC](https://answers.ros.org/users/836/johnc/) on 2011-12-01**:
sorry, I tried to upgrade to electric but did not find uvc_camera.

**Comment by [JohnC](https://answers.ros.org/users/836/johnc/) on 2011-12-01**:
sorry, I tried to upgrade to electric but did not find uvc_camera.

**Comment by [JohnC](https://answers.ros.org/users/836/johnc/) on 2011-12-01**:
Thanks for your answer. I was using unstable on ubuntu 11.04.